# How to scrape a website for time-series data

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm looking to scrape a currency exchange for time-series data so I can do some analysis. I know I can use javascript libraries to scrape a website one time, but I want time series data. So would I essentially create a JSON Object that has the format :

```
{ 
  ExchangeRateTimeseries: 
     [Timestamp: xxxxxx, Symbols: { symbol1: symbol1rate, symbol2: symbol2rate, symbol3: symbol3rate.....}]
}
```

?? So I can basically execute a scrape request every say 1 minute and then make a JSON object with the respective timestamps and the exchange rates? Does this make sense? I'm open for any input. Thank you.

Comment: If you can scrape a site once for certain values then yes, you can scrape it at regular intervals and put those values in an array. Which part are you having trouble with? If you're starting from scratch this question is too broad for this site.

Comment: Does the exchange have an API you could use before you took the scraping approach?

Comment: You might check the EULA / TOS if you're authenticating with the server, this could get your account banned.  If anonymous it's legal but could get your IP blocked.  As above if there is an API it's much better to use that.